# if else issue in parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-lazyload

I have a JSON feed that has three different possibilities for where a photo URL might be as I'm parsing it and using the lazyload plugin.

For instance, if there's no photo, it's undefined (see below, I've tested that line solo and it works). If there's one photo, it'll be at data.value.items[i]["media:content"].url. If there's more than one photo, it'll be at data.value.items[i]["media:content"][i].url (where i in the media:content is 0, 1, 2, etc., depending on how many photos exist).

The links and headlines are flowing in fine. I'm only having an issue with the photos.

In the current version of this code, I can console log and see that everything appears to be either assigned the placeholder photo (green_app.jpg) or is linking to the actual photo. Yet I can't get that to show up on the page.

```
$.getJSON('JSON URL HERE', function(data) {
    console.log(data);  

    var output = '';

    $.each(data.value.items, function(i, item){
        if(typeof data.value.items[i]["media:content"] === "undefined"){
            console.log("No photo");
            image = 'images/green_app.jpg';
        }
        else if (typeof data.value.items[i]["media:content"] === "object"){
            console.log("1 photo");
            image = data.value.items[i]["media:content"].url;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Multi photos");
            image = data.value.items[i]["media:content"][i].url;
        }

        console.log(image);

        output += '<ul class="media-list">';
        output += '<li class="media">';
        output += '<a class="pull-left" href="' + data.value.items[i].link  + '">';
        output += '<img data-original="' + image + '" class="media-object img-rounded lazy" height="120" width="120">';
        output += '</a><div class="media-heading"><a href="' + data.value.items[i].link  + '">';
        output += '<h4>' + data.value.items[i].title + '</h4></a></div></li></ul>';
    })

    $("#mainNews").html(output);
});

$(".lazy").lazyload();
```

Comment: Not related to question, but your code is vulnerable to XSS attack. You need to HTML encode all values you add to HTML

Comment: Isn't that kind of a last-step before I launch a site kind of thing? I honestly don't know much about the process of even much more than a couple anecdotes about how XSS attacks work, obviously.

Comment: Rewriting your code last thing before launch is never a good idea. How XSS work? What if your title="<script src="http://myserver/myscript.js">"? That means I can do inside that script anything I like, like sending your authentication cookie with AJAX request to me

Comment: Read on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just check

```
 else if (typeof data.value.items[i]["media:content"] === "object" && "url" in data.value.items[i]["media:content"]){
     console.log("1 photo");
     image = data.value.items[i]["media:content"].url;
  }
```